# Finding numbers in a .txt file of thousands of numbers ending in a specific set of 4 numbers

Tags: python, regex

What I currently have written I can find specific numbers starting with but I need numbers ending with.

The data file looks like this:

```
1231231234
1231231234
1231231234
etc...
```

My code:

```
import re
with open("test.txt") as f:
   with open("testoutput.txt", "w") as f1:
       for line in f:
           if re.match("^123", line):
               f1.write(line)
```

Comment: Hint: check out what `$` does.

Comment: Please correct your indent

Comment: $ did not shoot an error but did not extract and write any numbers to the file.

Answer (score 0):

Its not clear why you're using `^123` to match your number.

In regex paradigm, "ending with something" translates to "something + end of line". Which is `something$` in most regex dialects. Take a look into [official python doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax) on this.

Not regarding actual question, hint: you can write multiple context managers in one line, like

```
with open("test.txt") as f, open("testoutput.txt", "w") as f1:
    ...
```

Comment: I am aiming to pull the full number with any number matching the last 3 numbers. The reason I was using ^123 is because I was using this script to pull numbers starting with but now I need to pull numbers ending with.

Comment: I guess, `\d+123$` should help

Comment: @juliosalvat: If you think that the answer helped you, please consider upvoting/accepting it (green tick on the left).

Comment: I tried upvoting but I got a warning pop up saying it can not be shown publicly because I have a reputation of less than 15. Thanks tho this really helped me.

Answer (score 0):

No regex needed, you could very well use `endswith`:

```
string = """
1231231234

1231231234

1231231234
888
"""

numbers = [line 
    for line in string.split("\n") 
    if line and not line.endswith('1234')]
print(numbers)
```

Which yields

```
['888']
```

---

Or, the other way round:

```
string = """
1231231234

1231231234

1231231234
888
"""

numbers = [line 
    for line in string.split("\n") 
    if line and line.endswith('1234')]
print(numbers)
# ['1231231234', '1231231234', '1231231234']
```